# Perl: Strange behaviour of s///g

Tags: regex, perl, replace

I have a regex which captures some parts of a string. I want to remove/replace some character of one of the captured string using s///g but it has a strange behaviour. With tr///d it gives the desired result.

First here the output of what I want using the code with tr:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $x = '01_02_john_jane_fred_2017.xml';

$x =~ /^(\d\d)_(\d\d)_((?:[a-z]+_?)+)_(\d{4})\.xml$/;

my $desc = $3;

$desc =~ tr/_//d;

print "---print \$1: $1\n";
print "---print \$2: $2\n";
print "---print \$3: $3\n";
print "---print \$desc: $desc\n";
print "---print \$4: $4\n";
```

This is what I get:

```
D:\>perl p0018.pl
---print $1: 01
---print $2: 02
---print $3: john_jane_fred
---print $desc: johnjanefred
---print $4: 2017
```

But if I use s///g instead of tr///d:

```
$desc =~ s/_//g;
```

I get this:

```
D:\>perl p0018.pl
Use of uninitialized value $1 in concatenation (.) or string at p0018.pl line 14.
---print $1:
Use of uninitialized value $2 in concatenation (.) or string at p0018.pl line 15.
---print $2:
Use of uninitialized value $3 in concatenation (.) or string at p0018.pl line 16.
---print $3:
---print $desc: johnjanefred
Use of uninitialized value $4 in concatenation (.) or string at p0018.pl line 18.
---print $4:
```

Is there an explanation for this behaviour? How I could use s instead of tr to get the desired result?

Comment: It looks like you are using Windows, and you don't know how to copy output from `cmd`. You need to right-click, pick _Select_ (or _Mark_ or something), then select and press the _Enter_ key. Or read https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/copy-to-the-clipboard-from-the-windows-command-prompt/.

Comment: I would suggest `/^(\d+)_(\d+)_(\w+)_(\d+)\.xml$/` unless you can't trust the format of your filenames and you need to *validate* them as well as parsing the information.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`m//` and `s///` set the match variables after a successful match, while `tr///` doesn’t, since it’s just a character-by-character transformation. Using `s///` here just discards the previous values of `$1`, `$2`, &c. because you’re doing another match. Just bind them to different variables before using them.

```
my $x = '01_02_john_jane_fred_2017.xml';
$x =~ /^(\d\d)_(\d\d)_((?:[a-z]+_?)+)_(\d{4})\.xml$/;

my $first = $1;
my $second = $2;
my $desc = $3;
my $year = $4;
$desc =~ s/_//g;

print "---print \$first: $first\n";
print "---print \$second: $second\n";
# ...
```

Comment: Note that it's only *successful* regex pattern matches that alter the number variables; a failed match will leave them untouched. Also, `tr///` doesn't affect them because it doesn't use regex patterns: it is a simple character range.

Comment: @Borodin In my real case I tested the match (if ...) before I capture. I omitted this in SO to simplify the problem. But, thank you for this information. I didn't know that.